# T-Cell Receptor Receptor-Associated Immune Receptor Activation Motifs (ITAMs) Inconsistency

Tags: cell-biology, immune-system, protein-structure, protein-binding, receptor

In reading the information associated with the cytoplasmic machinery of the T-Cell Receptor (TCR), the one tyrosine motif that is consistently mentioned is the receptor-associated immune receptor activation motifs (ITAMs). All sources I can find on the motif says the sequence is YxxL/Ix<sub>(6-8)</sub>YxxL/I [[1]](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41577-018-0020-8). However, in the CD3ζ chain of the TCR in homo-sapiens, this sequence is not present according to separate protein structure and sequence sources [[2](https://www.rcsb.org/3d-view/2HAC/0),[3](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/6JXR_a)]. It is only the TCRβ chain that has this sequence motif in it [[4]](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/6JXR). The importance of the ITAM seems to be it is the binding location of the protein ZAP-70 (which stands for Zeta-chain-associated protein kinase 70), therefore given the name it is canonically associated with just the zeta chain not the TCRβ chain, what is the ITAM truly then?

The sequence seems to be conserved in murine TCR sequences [[5]](https://cshperspectives.cshlp.org/content/2/6/a002485.full.pdf+html), however, many of the articles being written are not specifically talking about murine TCR structures.

Is this an oversight in regard to the lack of clarity in the writing of the papers describing the involvement of ITAMs in TCR signaling or what is the source of the disagreement between the ITAM sequence and what is seen with the protein structure?